# Working make file example

Tags: j2objc

Sorry to appear so basic in this place.
1/ Shall I use both a make file and build settings + build phases, or alternatively a make file or build* ?
2/ There is two examples of make files in the wiki docs but neither of them is working.

So could you please post a fully working make file ?

Thank you.

Regards

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take some time to read [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

j2objc's build uses make, so it's the best source of working make files. [The jsr305 sub-project](https://github.com/google/j2objc/blob/master/jsr305/Makefile) is a good example since it's small. It uses [make macros](https://github.com/google/j2objc/tree/master/make) we've found useful building larger projects.